# Mongo is not defined - problem while loading data from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a console bug. please help
Mongo is not defined - problem while loading data from the server

```
C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  

ReferenceError: mongo is not defined
    at C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\routes\info.js:38:70
    at C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:122:13
    at _each (C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:46:13)
    at Object.async.each (C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:121:9)
    at C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\routes\info.js:34:31
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
    at C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:861:16
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:171:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:505:3)
    at nextFunction (C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\FINISH\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:660:7)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^0.9.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.10.2",
    "bson": "^4.2.2",
    "client-sessions": "^0.7.0",
    "express": "^4.11.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^2.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code snippet showing how you have implemented it.

Comment: Please post your actual code that's using `mongo`. It sounds like you might have a missing `require` or other variable initialization.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I added the code in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 38 of info.js references `mongo`: `mongo.ObjectID...`, but `mongo` does not exist in that file. You need to add `const mongo = require('mongodb')` to the top of the file along with your `require` of the `async` module. And for future reference, you can edit posts on StackOverflow rather than replying with detail as an answer.